# Trying to implement Done/Cancel buttons on number keypad, but error is given when textfield is selected in simulator

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a textfield which is number only.  I'm trying to implement a done/cancel buttons on the keypad to get rid of the keypad.

In the simulator when I select the textfield to enter an amount I get the following error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-       
[durood keyboardWillShow:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7644900'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1c93012 0x10d0e7e 0x1d1e4bd 0x1c82bbc 0x1c8294e 0xb914f9 0x1ced0c5 0x1c47efa 0xac5bb2     
0x3c5777 0x3be929 0x3c08a2 0x3c0931 0x3c097b 0x3ba117 0x123386 0x122e29 0x2e63c3 0x2e8442   
0x2df85a 0x2de99b 0x2e00df 0x2e2d2d 0x2e2cac 0x2daa28 0x47972 0x47e53 0x25d4a 0x17698 
0x1beedf9 0x1beead0 0x1c08bf5 0x1c08962 0x1c39bb6 0x1c38f44 0x1c38e1b 0x1bed7e3 0x1bed668 
0x14ffc 0x209d 0x1fc5 0x1)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

Here is the code in my h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

int dcounter;
int total;
int enteramount;

@interface durood : UIViewController {

IBOutlet UILabel *dcount;
IBOutlet UILabel *dtotal;
IBOutlet UITextField *numberTextField;
```

Here is the code in my m file for the extra buttons to be added to the keypad:

```
[super viewDidLoad];

UIToolbar *numberToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)];
numberToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
numberToolbar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                       [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Cancel" 
style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(cancelNumberPad)],
                       [[UIBarButtonItem  
alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil],
                       [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Apply"  
style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(doneWithNumberPad)],
                       nil];
[numberToolbar sizeToFit];
numberTextField.inputAccessoryView = numberToolbar;
}

-(void)cancelNumberPad{
[numberTextField resignFirstResponder];
numberTextField.text = @"";
}

-(void)doneWithNumberPad{
NSString *numberFromTheKeyboard = numberTextField.text;
[numberTextField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

What am I missing?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  The keypad should look like this:[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crash is coming from the fact that `durood` does not have a method implementation for `keyboardWillShow:`.

Are you subscribing for notifications, like `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification`? You likely added a `@selector(keyboardWillShow)`, but didn't actually create the method implementation.

Comment: I don't think I am subscribing to notifications.  Sorry I'm completeley new to Xcode.  How would I do this please, and where would I put this i.e. what file (app delegate/m file)?

Comment: Regardless of the notifications thing, somewhere in your code you are calling `keyboardWillShow:` without a method implementation. Perhaps you could pase a bit of your `viewDidLoad` method?

Comment: oh yes you're right I am must have put it in when trying different methods